# can't get asp.net membership provider to work with mysql

Tags: mysql, asp.net-membership

I have been working my way through the confusing tutorials in the MySql Connector/Net to set up an ASP.NET membership database.  I'm not actually going to use the web site for anything; I'm working on a WPF application that uses the ASP.NET Membership Provider for authentication.  We are considering a switch to MySQL for our embedded database and I need to get the membership database created.

Unfortunately, as far as I know there is no SQL script for generating the MySql ASP.NET Membership database schema.  The only way I know how to do it is to create a web site and have it generate the schema.

However, I can't get the provider to work.  Here's the error I'm getting back when I go to set up security:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'mysql.web' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (C:\Users\tony.vitabile\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite1\web.config line 48)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found my problem.  I had the wrong path to the DLL in the `type` setting of the provider in the configuration.  I also had to add the version, culter, and public token to get it to work.